# Sorting Substring Array by Their Frequencies - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, sorting

I generate an array of substrings with a given string and a substring length using this code:

```
function NthFrequencyCount(string,length){

    var frequency = {};
    for(var i = 0;i < string.length-length;i++){
        var char = string.substring(i,i+length);

        if(char.indexOf(' ') === -1){
            if(frequency[char] === undefined)
                frequency[char] = 1;
            else
                frequency[char]++;
        }
    }
    return frequency;
};
```

The next thing that I would like to do is to sort the substrings by their frequencies.

How do I do that?

Comment: sounds like a good plan. You have not asked a question though? What is your question?

Comment: Are you having further issues moving on? If your problem is solved then you should mark the answer that helped resolving the problem as **accepted**. This helps other people who have the same question. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from your code. See explanations in comments:

```
// frequency object is populated
entries = [];
for (var key in frequency) { // convert freqeuncy into array of entries
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    entries.push({ key:key, freq:frequency[key] });
  }
}

entries.sort(function(a, b) { // sort entries by freq
    return a.freq - b.freq;
}).map(function(entry) { // pluck out only the key, which is the substring
    return entry.key;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have an array of the substring, and then you can provide the comparator to the the JS `sort` method to do the sorting.

Assume you have an array of the substrings, namely `substrings`:

```
var frequencies = nthFrequencyCount(string, length);
substrings.sort(function (a, b) {
    // This sort the substrings in ascending order of frequency
    return frequencies[a] - frequencies[b];
});
```

Comment: I don't have the "substrings" array,what I get from my "NthFrequencyCount" is an array that in which you use the substring to access the data,and the data is a number which represent the frequency.

Comment: your NthFrequencyCount returns an object, not an array, so you cannot sort it. If you can't create or access such array before hand, that @LingZong's solution above would help to create that array from your frequencies objects.